# Retrieving data from form results on external website with PHP

Tags: php, forms, input

How I might go about writing a script that inputs and submits a form on an external website, allowing me to then harvest the results?

Obviously the forms I'm referring to make use of `$_POST` rather than `$_GET`, otherwise I could use the full URL with query string to harvest whatever I need.

Any pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated - not even entirely sure what to search for, I only seem to be able to find how to either harvest data from raw html or process forms (both of which I can do, neither of which are what I'm looking for).

Comment: you should give a look at http://www.php.net/curl expecially http://it.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php#91809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer is bedind this doors: [PHP: cURL - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Thanks, I'll get stuck in. :)